# laravel hybridauth login Undefined index: oauth_token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, hybridauth

i used this tutorial for hybridauth and laravel: [link](http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/)

I set twitters key and secret, now when i go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/social` i get error:

```
Undefined index: oauth_token
```

Does anyone know what can be a problem here?

My config:

```
// in hybridauth config array
"base_url"   => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/auth",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the name of the fields in your database,

the field for the user id must be just "id",

and the field for the password must be just "password".

That was the issue for me, I hope this help you. 
(late answer, I know, but may help someone else)

Have a nice day :D